# Why would CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting lock or otherwise perform poorly

Tags: azure

I am experiencing performance issues with my Azure application.  Application Insights shows a hot path which resolves to a call to `Microsoft.Azure.CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting()`.  Here is the hot-path - you can see it waits for 5 seconds:

[![App insights hot path][1]][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEPXw.png

Of note:

- this code has been running for years without hiccup as far as I know
- I recently added deployment slots to the application.  Seeing as these have their own slot-settings, perhaps there is some kind of issue there??